# How to perform image classification with SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin and BIP files?

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, imagery, landsat, land-classification

I have multiband satellite images BIP format, Landsat TM/ETM containing 7/8 bands respectively along with a separate header file, some of them corrected by nearest neighbour classifier.

I'm working in QGIS and need to segment specific regions of these images. I saw good examples with TIFF images format, but when proceeding with BIP format the SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin" gives me different kind of errors like not attribute is found in images, can't perform the instruction, or it's just not loaded.

Could someone guide me on this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: After several days trying to find a way to classify these images I have converted them into Geotiff and work from it using Grass & gdal plugin. If still someone knows a better way to do this, please leave your comment.